# Asynctask, porque recibe un array el método doInBackground()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

[image: The example]

Hola a todos,
En un curso que estoy cogiendo de android, hay un ejemplo para el uso de la clase  `AsyncTask`, pero hay algo que no entiendo porque lo hizo.

¿Para que sirve esta parte del código?

```
URL searchUrl = urls [0];
```

Gracias pro la ayuda por adelantado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación de Asynctask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) el primer tipo definido, en este caso `URL` define que el método [doInBackground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) recibira un array, en el caso del ejemplo que muestras, los elementos son de tipo `URL`.

```
public class GithubQueryTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String[][] doInBackground(URL... urls) {
```

Esto significa que puedes enviar varios valores; en este caso si defines varios valores de tipo `URL` para ejecutar tu Asynctask][1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), como ejemplo:

```
new GithubQueryTask().execute(url1, url2, url3, url4, url5);
```

Recibiras estos valores en un array, estos valores los puedes obtener mediante su indice:

```
public class GithubQueryTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String[][]> {

    @Override
    protected String[][] doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        URL searchUrl1 = urls[0];
        URL searchUrl2 = urls[1];
        URL searchUrl3 = urls[2];
        URL searchUrl4 = urls[3];
        URL searchUrl5 = urls[4];
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Como puedes ver en el código, el método doInBackground recibe como parámetros (URL... urls) y esto que significa?

Eso significa que espera un array, es lo mismo que si pusieses URL[] urls.

Por lo tanto, al hacer

```
URL searchUrl = urls[0];
```

A searchUrl le estás asignando el valor del primer elemento del array que pasas al hacer la llamada

```
new GitHubQueryTask.execute("Este parámetro");
```

Como ves, en el ejemplo le he pasado un string a pelo (en tu caso un objeto tipo URL) no un array, esto también vale, eso si, tienes que tener en cuenta que al hacerlo así, el array solo va a tener una posición.

Si fuese necesario pasarle más de una URL, le puedes pasar un array de URLs.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la explicacion, lo entendi muy bien.